Skip TLS Handshake certificate to save Proxy bandwidth
My proxy is charging me for the whole request including TLS handshake -- basically anything that goes through their servers. (Which is fair I guess)
Now when I was debugging my requests, they weigh 8KB, where 6KB is just the certificate that's being downloaded each time from the server.
I want to avoid that by using Session Resumption.
I'm scratching my head over how to use it with aiohttp library.
async def fetch(self, session, url, headers, params=None):
        proxy = "http://user:pass@proxy.com:8888/"
        try:
            async with session.get(url, headers=headers, params=params, proxy=proxy) as response:
                return await response.json()
        except aiohttp.ContentTypeError as e:
            # Handle the specific ContentTypeError silently
            pass
        except Exception as e:
            error_info = f'Error fetching data: {e}'
            self.error_messages.append(error_info)
            pass

I'm not sure how to get the session id and reuse it.
Any guidance is highly appreciated.

Not sure on the answer, but I suspect you'll want to pass a custom SSLContext: https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html#ssl.SSLContext
You could even just load the server's certificate directly. Enabling ALPN might also reduce the bandwidth slightly.

Another question popped in my mind.. Do I control how the server responds? or does the proxy have to do the handshake anyways?
